# View controller lifecycle methods callback in framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on a framework project where i need callback when a view controller is presented.
In android we have [Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks) to achieve the same.
I'm trying to achieve the same in iOS to but i could not find any way after spending more then 24 hrs on internet.

If anyone have done it before please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about knowing when some other view controller is presented or when your view controller is presented?

Comment: https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/f06f30fa63/UIViewController_Class_Reference_2x_ddcaa00c-87d8-4c85-961e-ccfb9fa4aac2.png

Comment: if you want call back in just one controller you can use delegate and if you want call back in multiple controllers than you can use notification center

Comment: @rmaddy when view controller presented in app which will integrate my framework.

Comment: @DevilDecoder i want for each view controller in app but without telling the app

Comment: @MadLeo than you can use notifications for callback in multiple controllers

Comment: @DevilDecoder i'm working on framework, others will implement the app then how i can register for notification

Comment: Unless your framework includes a view controller class that the users of your framework must extend, there is no way to know that a view controller has been presented unless your API provides some call that your framework users must explicitly call to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the least intrusive way to achieve your goal would be creating a view controller subclass that posts a NSNotification in each step of the lifecycle, and then subclass it in your app's view controllers.